# Configuring Vim to only check spelling in text regions

Tags: spelling, vim

Is there a way to configure Vim so that it only checks spelling in the text regions of TeX files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the [vim-latexsuite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) spell-checking works fine. Since it makes typing latex files a lot easier and faster I can only recommend it to every LaTeX-writing vim user.

Comment: The screenshots show only `gvim`. Does it offer usefull functionaility with regular `vim`?

Comment: @Bernhard I don't see a reason for it not to work in vim.

Comment: @Caramir: It is specifically showing menus and submenus. Do you have first hand experience with it?

Comment: @Bernhard You don't need to use the menus. All shortcuts (and the spell-checking enhancements) should work in vim as well. You just need to remember the commands instead of being able to click on them. Personally, I use gvim, but rarely actually use the menus.

Answer (score 1):

Use the project specific dictionary for latex given at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=499. It will remove all the keywords from being marked by vim's spellchecker.

Comment: Could you provide a more specific pointer?  This seems to be to an old spell checking package (not the built-in one), and I can't locate anything very TeX-specific in the files.